# What does Tree(Int,Int) mean in haskell?

Tags: haskell, tree, tuples

I am learning data structures in Haskell right now. I saw something like:

```
  Tree(Int,Int)
```

Does that mean tuple of trees? I'm trying to write something like:

```
  data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving (Eq,Show)

  weight :: (Tree Integer) -> Tree(Integer,Integer)

  weight (Node left leaf right) = Node (leaf, (sum left) + (sum right)) 
                          where 
                          sum (Leaf a) = 0
                          sum (Node left leaf right) = leaf + sum left + sum right
```

But I am getting couldn't match error.

What I want to get is the weight of each Node and return it as a tuple, and a single leaf doesn't have a weight.

Comment: what about right part of Node? shouldn't it be `Node (Leaf, (sum left) + (sum right), Leaf)` or something like that?

Comment: It means a tree of tuples, not a tuple of trees. (More specifically, it's a tree of pairs.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix the immediate error, you need to provide three arguments to the `Node` constructor:

```
weight (Node left leaf right) = Node (weight left) 
                                     (leaf, (sum left) + (sum right)) 
                                     (weight right)
                          where 
                          sum (Leaf a) = 0
                          sum (Node left leaf right) = leaf + sum left + sum right
```

and perhaps a base case

```
weight (Leaf a) = Leaf (a,0)
```

..but I'm not sure this is what you intended:

```
ghci> weight (Node (Leaf 100) 10 (Node (Leaf 20) 30 (Leaf 40)))
Node (Leaf (100,0)) (10,30) (Node (Leaf (20,0)) (30,0) (Leaf (40,0)))
```

The values at the leaves are ignored and the second element in each pair is the subtree total.

### Sum less frequently

There's a lot of repetition in summing the left and right subtrees, when you're calculating their weight too. Why not reuse the value?

We can read off the sum of a subtree by taking the second element of the top pair:

```
topsecond :: Tree (a,a) -> a
topsecond (Leaf (x,y)) = y
topsecond (Node _ (x,y) _) = y
```

So let's use that to get the sum

```
weigh (Leaf a) = Leaf (a,0)
weigh (Node left value right) = Node newleft (value,total) newright where
       newleft = weigh left
       newright = weigh right
       leftsum = topsecond newleft
       rightsum = topsecond newright
       total = leftsum + value + rightsum
```

### Add up differently

In a comment you mention we should have `(10,190)` for the node tagged 10. That's the sum of everything below, but not including the current item. This means that the total weight of a subtree can be obtained by adding its subtrees' weight to the current value:

```
addTopPair :: Num a => Tree (a,a) -> a  -- or Tree (Integer,Integer) -> Integer
addTopPair (Leaf (x,y)) = x+y
addTopPair (Node _ (x,y) _) = x+y
```

and then

```
weighUnder (Leaf a) = Leaf (a,0)
weighUnder (Node left value right) = Node newleft (value,total) newright where
       newleft = weighUnder left
       newright = weighUnder right
       leftsum = addTopPair newleft
       rightsum = addTopPair newright
       total = leftsum + rightsum
```

giving

```
ghci> weighUnder (Node (Leaf 100) 10 (Node (Leaf 20) 30 (Leaf 40)))
Node (Leaf (100,0)) (10,190) (Node (Leaf (20,0)) (30,60) (Leaf (40,0)))
```

and

```
ghci> > weighUnder $ Node (Node (Leaf (-8)) (-12) (Node (Leaf 9) 3 (Leaf 6))) 5 (Node (Leaf 2) 14 (Leaf(-2)))
Node (Node (Leaf (-8,0)) (-12,10) (Node (Leaf (9,0)) (3,15) (Leaf (6,0)))) (5,12) (Node (Leaf (2,0)) (14,0) (Leaf (-2,0)))
```

as required.

Comment: not exactly.i think i expressed my self wrong. for example for 10 it should be (10,190)

Comment: @nbdip The sum of everything _except_ the current value?

Comment: yeah.for example ;
tree=Node (Node (Leaf (-8)) (-12) (Node (Leaf 9) 3  (Leaf 6))) 5 (Node (Leaf 2) 14  (Leaf(-2)))
and for weigh tree it should be (3,15),(-12,10),(5,12),(14,0)